# Concatenating two dynamic string arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
template <typename Object>
class Vector1 {
public:
explicit Vector1(const Object & value = Object()) : size_{0} {
    array_ = new Object{value};
    size_++;
}

Vector1(const Vector1 & rhs) : size_{rhs.size_} { //copy constructor
    array_ = new Object[size_];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        array_[i] = rhs.array_[i];
    }
}

Vector1 & operator=(const Vector1 & rhs) { //copy assignment operator
    array_ = new Object[rhs.size_];

    if (this != &rhs) {
        size_ = rhs.size_;
        for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
            array_[i] = rhs.array_[i];
        }
    }

    return *this; 
}

Vector1(Vector1 && rhs) : array_{rhs.array_}, size_{rhs.size_} { //move constructor
    rhs.array_ = nullptr;
    rhs.size_ = 0;
}

Vector1 & operator=(Vector1 && rhs) { //move assignment operator
    if (this != &rhs) {
        std::swap(size_, rhs.size_);
        std::swap(array_, rhs.array_);
    }

    return *this;
}

void print(ostream & out) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        out << array_[i] << " ";
    }
}

void ReadVector1() {
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter a size: ";
    cin >> size_;

    array_ = new Object[size_];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
        cout << "Enter element " << count + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> array_[i];
        count++;
    }
}

size_t Size() const {
    return size_;
}

**Vector1 operator+=(Vector1 & rhs) {
    size_t combosize = size_ + rhs.size_;
    Object combo[combosize];
    int count = 0, rhscount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < combosize; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            combo[i] = array_[count];
            count++;
        }
        else {
            combo[i] = rhs.array_[rhscount];
            rhscount++;
        }
    }
    std::swap(combosize, rhs.size_);
    std::swap(combo, rhs.array_);
    return *this;
}
Vector1 operator+(const Vector1 & rhs) const {
    Vector1 temp(*this);
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}**

~Vector1() { //destructor
    delete[] array_;
}

private:
    size_t size_; 
    Object *array_;
};

template <typename Object>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Vector1<Object> & rhs) {
    rhs.print(out);
    return out;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   Vector1<string> a, b;

   a.ReadVector1(); //user provides input for Vector1 a
   cout << a << endl;

   b.ReadVector1(); //user provides input for Vector1 b
   cout << b << endl; 

   cout << a + b << endl; //concatenates the two Vector1s

   Vector1<string> d = a + b;
   cout << d;

   return 0;
}
```

The above is my code (thus far). What I'm trying to accomplish is to concatenate a's dynamic array with b's dynamic array (I cannot use vectors or any STLs, this is meant to be a rudimentary imitation of a vector).

Example:

The user inputs a size of 2 for a and inputs "Hello" and "World".
The user inputs a size of 2 for b and inputs "Goodbye" and "World". 
The output should be "Hello World Goodbye World".

I highlighted what I think the problem is, which is the overloading of + and the += operators. My reasoning is that I create a new array, fill it up with the value's from a and b, swap the values, and then return the supposed concatenation.

My reasoning may not seem sound because frankly, I'm quite confused on how to proceed with this.

Comment: Why doesn't `Vector1` also use copy / swap in the `operator=`?  It is not exception safe.

Comment: Why isn't it exception safe? Should I replace the for loop with a swap?

Comment: I should clarify and say that the assignment operator is wrong.  You failed to `delete[]` the memory that `_array` pointed to (mistake).  If you try to fix this by issuing a `delete [] _array;` up front, then it is not exception safe since the subsequent call to `new[]` in that function may throw an exception, thus messing up your object since you've destroyed `_array`.    Instead of all of this, just implement the copy / swap on the function.

Comment: You are also missing some very important functions, such as a constructor for `Vector1` that takes a size argument.  If you had that, then the `operator +=` becomes very simple.

Comment: In your `+=` operator overload, you're doing a grave mistake of returning a double pointer, instead of a reference. Have your function return a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code concerning `operator +=`.

First, `operator +=` should return a reference to the current object, i.e. `return *this;`.  It shouldn't return a brand new `Vector1` object.

Second, this line:

```
size_t combosize = size_ + rhs.size_;
Object combo[combosize];
```

is not valid ANSI C++, since arrays must be declared with a compile-time expression to denote the number of entries.  Since `combosize` is a runtime value, it cannot be used.

You are probably using the GCC compiler, where there is a Variable Length Array extension, but again, this is an *extension* and is not really part of the C++ language.

Also, you are missing some constructors that would make writing `operator +=` much easier.  The constructor for `Vector1` that you're lacking is this one:

```
Vector1::Vector1(size_t num) : array_(new Object[num]), size_(num) {}
```

This constructor just constructs a `Vector1` with `num` entries.

---

Given the above, to fix the issues:

```
Vector1& operator+=(const Vector1 & rhs) 
{
    // create a temporary vector 
    Vector1 temp(size_ + rhs.size_);

    // copy elements to temp array
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++) 
       temp.array_[i] = array_[i];

    // copy elements from rhs to temp array
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = size_; i < size_ + rhs.size_; i++, j++) 
       temp.array_[i] = rhs.array_[j];

    // assign and return
    *this = temp;
    return *this;
}

Vector1 operator+(const Vector1 & rhs) const 
{
    Vector1 temp(*this);
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

Note that in `operator +=` we just create a temporary `Vector1`, fill it up with the values from ***this** and the passed in `Vector1`, and assign it to the current object.  The `*this = temp;` line requires a working assignment operator.  See the next section below.

---

The other issue is your `Vector1::operator=` is incorrect.  It does not deallocate the memory allocated to `_array` previously, thus you have a memory leak.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the copy / swap you used in the `operator=(Vector1 &&)`:

```
Vector1 & operator=(const Vector1 & rhs) 
{ 
    Vector1 temp(rhs);
    std::swap(size_, temp.size_);
    std::swap(array_, temp.array_);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Paul, I really appreciate your help. Thanks for explaining everything. I also fixed my copy assignment operator. Again, thank you very much.